# How to assert metrics publication with reactor-test

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'd like to assert if a reactive flow publishes certain [metrics](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_publisher_metrics). I wasn't able to trigger metrics publication with StepVerifier, nor has it methods to assert anything related with metrics.

Subscribing the flow does trigger metrics but this requires managing more test code; do you have any suggestions to turn on metrics publication with StepVerifier ?

Answer (score 0):

Project reactor detects if `micrometer` is present and uses the **global** registry provided by micrometer. You can test your code by amending the `globalRegistry` be sure to clean the registry before (and if you like after) each test.

You could then test the metric generation by providing a `SimpleMeterRegistry`.

This is not perfect, as it fiddles with the static registry

```java
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Metrics;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MockClock;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.simple.SimpleConfig;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.simple.SimpleMeterRegistry;
import java.util.Set;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

class ReactorTest {

  @Test
  void happyPathSuccess() {
    Set<MeterRegistry> registries = Metrics.globalRegistry.getRegistries();
    registries.forEach(Metrics.globalRegistry::remove);

    SimpleMeterRegistry simple = new SimpleMeterRegistry(SimpleConfig.DEFAULT, new MockClock());
    Metrics.addRegistry(simple);

    Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just("moooep moeeeep")).name("demo").metrics()
        .as(StepVerifier::create)
        .expectNext("moooep moeeeep")
        .expectComplete()
        .verify();

    long count = simple.get("demo.flow.duration")
        .tag("status", "completed")
        .tag("type", "Mono")
        .timer()
        .count();
    Assertions.assertEquals(1, count);
  }

}
```